# convert tiff to netcdf

Tags: python, tiff, netcdf, netcdf4, rasterio

i try to convert a tiff to netcdf file. errors is saying index error:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import rasterio


with rasterio.drivers():
    src=rasterio.open(r"ia.tiff","r")
    dst_transform=src.transform
    dst_width=src.width
    dst_height=src.height
    print (dst_transform)
    xmin = dst_transform[0]
    xmax = dst_transform[0] + dst_transform[1]*dst_width
    print (xmax)
    min = dst_transform[3] + dst_transform[5]*dst_height
    print(ymin)
    ymax = dst_transform[3]

    dst_width=dst_width+1
    dst_height=dst_height+1
    outf=Dataset(r'ia.nc','w',format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')
    lats=np.linspace(ymin,ymax,dst_width)
    lons=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,dst_height)


    lat=outf.createDimension('lon',len(lats))
    lon=outf.createDimension('lat',len(lons))
    longitude=outf.createVariable('longitude',np.float64,('lon',))
    latitude=outf.createVariable('latitude',np.float64,('lat',))
    SHIA=outf.createVariable('SHIA',np.int8,('lon','lat'))

    outf.variables['longitude'][:]=lons
    outf.varibales['longitude'][:]=lat
    im=src.read()
    SHIA[:,:]=im

    outf.description="IA for"
    longitude.units="degrees east"
    latitude.units='degrees north'

    print ("created empty array")

    outf.close()




outf.close()
```

error is that index error: size of the data array does not conform to slice. can somebody take a look and help me where i did wrong. Much appreciated!

Comment: Not a solution, but for this kind of job it is usually very east to use GDAL, e.g. `gdal_translate -of NETCDF input.tiff output.nc`

Comment: Gdal does not work well with netcdf .

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's a bit iffy. But for this king of simple jobs, like translating between formats, I've always found it to be sufficient. Yes, you'll have to fix the attributes afterwards. Did you try it for your usecase?

Comment: I did not use gdal translate. I still creat a empty netcdf first then write the tiff it to it

Comment: Can you check the size of arrays? For instance: `np.shape(im)` and `np.shape(SHIA)`... Currently, I do not know which of the variables (longitude, latitude or im) do not conform to slice, but suspect im to SHIA.

Answer (score 0):

I use xarray for this kind of things. Create xarray DataArray for each variable you have (seems SHIA for yours). Create DataSet and related DataArray with it. Don't forget to set coordinate variables into Dataset as coordinate.

see:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html

Also you can convert your netcdf / tiff into dataframe and return again. But i wouldn't recommend this till you have to. Beause netcdf is multidimensional data and dataframe represent all data as cloning to one matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think of is to use the GDAL tool.

```
# Convert TIF to netCDF
gdal_translate -of netCDF -co "FOMRAT=NC4" ia.tif ia.nc

# Convert SHP to netCDF
gdal_rasterize -of netCDF -burn 1 -tr 0.01 0.01 input.shp output.nc
```